# How do I test if the values of a variable are NAs while using the paste() function to designate the variable?

Tags: r, loops, na, paste

I'd like to create a loop which replaces the values of several dummy variables by NA if the corresponding value of the original variable is NA as well (in order to recode a MCQ survey).

I have 19 questions, labeled Q1 through Q19, with dummy variables labeled Q1_[answer1], Q1_[answer2] etc. I made dummy variables with values 1 and 0, and instead of nesting another ifelse function which looks at the value of Q1, Q2 etc, I'd like to create a loop that takes the dummy variables automatically (by using grep("Q", [n], "_") where n increases as the loop progresses).

Here is essentially what my dataframe is like

```
df1 <- data.frame(Q1 = c("a", "b,c", NA, "a,b", "b", NA, "c"))

#this is done for the purposes of the loop, which I'm not including here
n <- 1
```

In order to check if the values of my Q1 are missing or not, I'd like to use the following code (or equivalent:

```
is.na(paste0("df$Q",n))

[1] FALSE
```

which would allow me to cycle through the different questions. However, this tests if "df$Q1" is equal to NA rather than looking at Q1 as a variable. I would like to find a way for it to be like if I had input "df$Q1" directly, which returns the list of results for the is.na() test for all values of the variable:

```
is.na(df$Q1)

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Is there a function like is.na or like paste0 which would allow me to do this easily?

Comment: `is.na(df[paste0("Q",n)])`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please could you explain the problem for specifically? It would be helpful if you could provide an example of your desired output

Comment: To add to the comment by @harre, using double brackets makes sure it's a vector and not a single-column data frame: `is.na(df[[paste0("Q", n)]])` which is the behaviour of `$`

Comment: This strikes me as a potential [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  I agree with @CaptainHat that a wider context would be helpful.  A tidyverse solution, avoiding `paste`ing and looping altogether might be similar to `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Q"), is.na))`.

Answer (score 1):

How you tackle this, may depend on what you intend to do with the result.  The simplest approach, as given in the comments, is to pass the vector through `is.na()`.

If you have a large data.frame this can be labourious.  Instead, a loop or the `sapply` may give what you need.

Extending your data.frame to demonstrate:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Q1 = c("a", "b,c", NA, "a,b", "b", NA, "c"), 
                  Q2 = c("a", "b,c", "a.b", "a,b", "b", "b", "c"),
                  Q3 = c("a", "b,c", NA, "a,b", "b", "c", NA))


  for(i in 1:length(names(df1))) {
    print(is.na(df1[[paste0("Q", i)]]))
  }
```

Gives:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

or `sapply(df1, is.na)`

```
        Q1    Q2    Q3
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

One trick is to use `sapply(df1, is.na) * 1`, which allows easy summation.